# How to convert text file into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a text which looks like the following

```
{"age": "52", "id": 1, "name": "Hulk"}
{"age": "33", "id": 2, "name": "Iron Man"}
```

I want to read the file and put it into an array of objects.

This is what I have done so far

```
const fs = require("fs");
const customerFile = fs.readFileSync("./customers.txt", "utf-8");
const customerArr = customerFile.split("\n");
```

As you can see I am splitting the file, which creates an array but I am stuck on how to convert the items in the array into objects. How can I do this?

Comment: Is each line a valid object? Can you use `JSON.parse`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you're working with is called [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/). You could try looking for a parser made specifically for it.

Or if you're reading it line by line into array, you can then map it to objects using `JSON.parse`.

```
customerArr.map(i => JSON.parse(i));
```